# Merge multiple unordered list items and convert them to a select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a BS 4 carousel and each slide contains a list of links. The links are loading some content when clicked. For better UX on mobile, I would like to merge all of these links (in carousel-items) into a single select option dropdown. It is also important the links stay functional so the appropriate content can be loaded when the items in the select dropdown are clicked.

I would like to do this with jQuery.

I have got it semi-working. I am missing the merging part though.

This is my HTML before conversion:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('1')">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('2')">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('3')">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('4')">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('5')">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('6')">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('7')">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('8')">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('9')">9</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('10')">10</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('11')">11</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('12')">12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

with this code:

```
$(function() {
  $('ul.majors').each(function() {
    var $select = $('<select />');

    $(this).find('a').each(function() {
      var $option = $('<option />');
      $option.attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html());
      $select.append($option);
    });

    $(this).replaceWith($select);
  });
});
```

And this is how the code looks like after conversion:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <select>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('1')">1</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('2')">2</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('3')">3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <select>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('4')">4</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('5')">5</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('6')">6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <select>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('7')">7</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('8')">8</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('9')">9</option>
    </select>        
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <select>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('10')">10</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('11')">11</option>
      <option value="javascript:switchContent('12')">12</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But how do I make it look like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('1')">1</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('2')">2</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('3')">3</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('4')">4</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('5')">5</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('6')">6</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('7')">7</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('8')">8</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('9')">9</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('10')">10</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('11')">11</option>
  <option value="javascript:switchContent('12')">12</option>
</select>
```

And do these values work/act like links when each option is selected?

**[Here's a Pen of what I have gotten so far](https://codepen.io/WpEmbraded/pen/MWJPgpm?editors=1010)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a single `<select>` first, then replace each `<ul>` with it.

```js
$(function() {
  var $select = $('<select />'); // Start building a <select>
  $('ul.majors a').each(function() { // Grab each hyperlink in each ul.majors
    var $option = $('<option />'); // Build 
    var $option = $('<option />').attr('value', $(this).attr('href')).html($(this).html()); // Update the value from the a's href
    $select.append($option); // Append the option to the <select>
  });

//      // Replace each ul.majors with the select:
//      $('ul.majors').each(function(){
//        $(this).replaceWith($select.clone()); // Need to clone it!
//      })

  // Or, to replace the entire carousel with the dropdown:
  $('.carousel-inner').replaceWith($select);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('1')">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('2')">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('3')">3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('4')">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('5')">5</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('6')">6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('7')">7</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('8')">8</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('9')">9</a></li>
    </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <ul class="majors">
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('10')">10</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('11')">11</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:switchContent('12')">12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is generating four dropdowns. I only need one.

Comment: @hnnnng So your intended end result is a single `carousel-item`? Or do you want to replace the entire carousel with the dropdown?

Comment: Yes. I want all list items to turn into a single select dropdown. The carousel and carousel-items will go away on mobile. I added a new class to the first ul so I can target it like this: https://codepen.io/WpEmbraded/pen/abpRzmZ?editors=1010  but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Why not just use a media query to hide the carousel and show the dropdown on mobile? That's generally the way to create a responsive site, rather than relying on JS/JQ to manipulate the DOM. In any case, I've edited my answer to include code that replaces the `.carousel-inner` with the new `<select>`, although you may want to replace the entire `.carousel` instead.

Comment: That makes sense, I can do that, and the edited answer looks great! Thank you for your help! :D

Comment: any idea why this solution does not work on mobile? It does work when I use the dev tool emulator in Chrome but it doesn't work on a mobile device and the list is empty. Is it the 'clone' that is not doing what's its supposed to do?

Comment: @hnnnng "Mobile device" is kind of vague. What specific devices and OSes have you tested this on?

Comment: that was a user error, sorry to blame the code. Everything's working fine now :D cheers